# About thread safe

Tags: neo4jclient

In https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting#threading-and-lifestyles, it mentioned that **You should only have one instance of it for each database.** Can I create more than one instance if I want to using multi-threads? For example, I want to do following things:

```
main() {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
        ( new System.Threading.Thread( newUser() ) ).Start() ;
}
void newUser() {
    var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
    client.Connect();
    /* do sth... */
}
```

For the reason that I want to simulate multi-user scenario. I tried this code and it seems like works well. Why is it said I can have only one instance for my DB in document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want! It's only a recommendation, in a typical scenario you would have only one instance and use it to save on extra calls to `Connect` etc.

The main thing we're trying to prevent is where someone has a method like this:

```
private static Element Get() {
    var client = new GraphClient(...);
    client.Connect();

    var q = client.Cypher.DOQUERYHERE
    return q.Results.Single();
}
```

Where *everytime* they call `Get` they create a new instance, the overhead of doing so would make the code very inefficient.

So, the long and short is - if you *want* to have multiple instances - of course you can, the scenario you have is a good reason.